# Joi validation: or() and xor() condition depending upon field value

Tags: javascript, joi, hapi

I have a schema that looks like this:

```
{
   a: joi.boolean(),
   b: joi.object(),
   c: joi.object()
}
```

Depending upon the value of field a = false, I want fields b or c to exist. If a is false, I want a xor condition on fields b and c.

I tried using when but I'm unable to find a perfect solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could find one possible solution for the problem. Here's it.

```
Joi.object({
 a: Joi.boolean(),
 b: Joi.object(),
 c: Joi.object()
})
.required()
.when( Joi.object({a:false}).unknown(), {
 then: Joi.object().or('a','b'),
 otherwise: Joi.object().oxor('a','b')
})
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```js
{
   a: Joi.boolean(),
   b: Joi.object().when('a', {
      is: false,
      then: Joi.object().required()
      otherwise: Joi.object()
   }),
   c: Joi.object().when('a', {
      is: false,
      then: Joi.object().required()
      otherwise: Joi.object()
   }),
}
```

I think you are looking for something like this.
[Joi.when()](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/v7.2.2/API.md#anywhenref-options)

Comment: Thanks Nicolae for answering.
The above solution will have an AND condition between b and c whenever a = false.
I want to have an OR and XOR condition between them.